# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I can’t run the suite() function from the bon() function, when I try to do it, it returns this error `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

(

I think it’s because I called the function wrong but I tried other ways and each time I have this mistake, and in my program, I can’t move the bon() function in the class screen manager, how to do plz?

Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, NumericProperty
kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

kv = """

#: import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition     
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#: import CardTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.CardTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: RiseInTransition()
    Question1:
        name: "question1"
    Question2:
        name: "question2"


<Question1>:

    label_wid : ratio

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "+1"
            pos: 270, 300
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press:
                root.mauvais()
        Button:
            text: "following"
            pos: 270, 240
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: 
                Clock.schedule_once(root.manager.suite, 0.75)

        Label:
            id: ratio
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 280,270
            font_size: 17
            color: 0,0,1,0.65

<Question2>:
"""


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    theText = StringProperty('')
    m = BooleanProperty(True)
    u = BooleanProperty(True)
    t = NumericProperty(0)

    def suite(root,text,self):
        self.m=True
        root.current = "question2"


class Question1(Screen):

    def mauvais(self):
        if  self.manager.m==True:
            self.manager.t += 1
            self.manager.theText = str(self.manager.t)
            self.manager.m=False

    def bon(self, root):
        if self.manager.u==True:
            self.manager.t = "bon"
            self.manager.theText = str(self.manager.t)
            self.manager.u=False    
            Clock.schedule_once(root.manager.suite, 0.75)  

    pass


class Question2(Screen):
    pass


class Quizz(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Quizz'
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 0.25)

        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Quizz().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `self` first then `root` in the `suite` function and remove the `text` argument. Also you need to remove the line `root.current = "question2"` line as there is no `current` property in `MyScreenManager` class. So, the `suite()` should be like below:

```
    def suite(self, root):
        self.m=True
        #root.current = "question2"
```